# register_acivation_hook function not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm learning the basics of creating a wordpress plugin. A function named as register_activation_hook is used to execute a specific function when the plugin is activated. I tried to use it, but it is not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'kk_aw_install');

    kk_aw_install(){
        echo "<script>alert('working')</script>";
    }
```

Comment: also you forgot `/` in closing script tag

Comment: added / in closing tag. not working. i ever tried echo "working".

it's showing "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error".

Comment: so, you'd better check plugin code rather than this 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'kk_al_install');
```

since your function name is `kk_al_install` not `kk_aw_install`

Comment: still not working. It's showing "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error." when i'm trying to activate plugin

Comment: Without more details, I cannot help you at this moment.